# telegram keyboard not showing non English languages chracters?

Tags: php, utf-8, keyboard, telegram-bot, non-english

I'm trying to write a php telegram bot in Persian which is a non English utf8 language.
when I try to send plain text in Persian to my client it works perfectly ok

```
    $array = [
    "chat_id" => $chat_id,
    "text" => $someNonEnglishText
];
$telegram->sendMessage($array);
```

but when I try to send keyboard data with the code below it just show some question marks like ???????????????? on my keyboard buttons

```
    $reply_markup = $telegram->replyKeyboardMarkup([
  'keyboard' => $someNonEnglishkeyboard, 
  'resize_keyboard' => true, 
  'one_time_keyboard' => true
   ]);
    $telegram->sendMessage([
  'chat_id' => $updates[0]->getMessage()->getChat()->getId(), 
  'text' => $something,
  'reply_markup' => $reply_markup
]);
```

an I'm perfectly sure that my bot php file is utf8 by running the following command in terminal
file myfile.php
whilch I got the answer:
surveyBot.php: PHP script, UTF-8 Unicode text

can someone help?

ps:the above code works perfectly fine for English keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using specific telegram framework, use following code (just for test purposes).
Change `chat_id` and `BOT_TOKEN` variables.
When this code runs, if you receive  healthy keyboard then your framework has problem with `utf-8`.($telegram belonging class in your code)

```
<?php

$chat_id = 123; //replace with your client chat id
define('BOT_TOKEN','1234:xyz'); //replace with your token

define('BOTAPI','https://api.telegram.org/bot' . BOT_TOKEN .'/');
$reply_markup = [
    'keyboard'          => [[['text' => 'سلام'], ['text' => 'خدانگهدار']]],
    'resize_keyboard'   => true,
    'one_time_keyboard' => true,
];
$data = [
    'chat_id'      => $chat_id,
    'text'         => 'utf-8 test',
    'reply_markup' => json_encode($reply_markup),
];
$ch = curl_init(BOTAPI . 'sendMessage');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked :-) but is there a way to fix and use the specific framework that I'm using?

Comment: @SaeidGhafouri , I am glad that it worked. It shows that  your framework  can not handling `utf-8`. As we don't know anything about your framework(neither name nor its sourcecode) so how can we help you! But as you know where is problem now, you can ask a new question about that specific framework and its support for `utf-8` or read its documentation. I say welcome to you as a new user of `stackoverflow.com` and it is more better that you participate in SELECTING BEST ANSWER and UPVOTE or DOWNVOTE answers or questions(for make it better as a member) .